# Error when adding new row to DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

I have a DataGridView with some text columns, combo box columns and an image column. When I try to add a blank new row by calling `DataGridView1.Rows.AddCopy(0)` I get the following error: `System.FormatException: Formatted value of the cell has a wrong type.`

The new row does not contain any data. When the user adds a new row through the GUI (i.e. not programmatically) there is no problem. Does anyone have any ideas as to what might be causing this issue?

Comment: How can someone add a row and not have it be programmatically?  This is a program, it has to be added via code.  Do you mean not with your code?  I believe your problem is there is nothing to copy, try `Rows.Insert(1,0)` instead.

Comment: I mean not within my code. The user can add the new row through DataGridView's internal code.

Comment: are you using databindings?

Comment: Are you giving it a type?

Comment: @Haxx: no I'm not using databindings.
@plast1K: I'm not giving it a type either, my understanding is that the new row should be already a `DataGridViewRow`.

Comment: k hang on i'll throw an example, maybe it helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does this help?

```
        // Create a new row on a datagridview
        var rowId = dataGridView1.Rows.Add();

        // fill the cells in the newly created row with your data
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowId].Cells[ColumnText.Name].Value = "";
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowId].Cells[ColumnCheckbox.Name].Value = true;
        dataGridView1.Rows[rowId].Cells[ColumnImage.Name].Value = null; // add image
```

Comment: Yes, thanks that works really well. I figured `AddCopy` would do that automatically. I'm not sure what the difference is between `Add` and `AddCopy`.

Comment: @HH - With AddCopy() you have to have something to copy, as I said in my example... Insert would also work.